# app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I am running an ec2 intance with ubuntu. I had to update from ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 and aftr doing it I started to receive the following error.

[image: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgZUY.png)]

After `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` I got the following error:

> [crit] 647#647: *9 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/UrRecalls/app.sock
> failed (2: No such file or directory)

The server is done with Django and I don't remember ever seeing the `app.sock` file. Any ideas about what could be causing this issue?

I have tried restarting the server, stopping and starting Nginx, and rebooting the server. I am pretty new at this and would appreciate any help.